# Populate mongoose subdoc in different location

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I'm populating a subdocument using my users model.  Right now all the info that is populated is being placed under `user_list[x]._id` so for instance `user_list[0]._id.displayName` but I'd like to have the data available like this: `user_list[0].displayName`

Is it possible to tell mongoose to extend `user_list[x]` with the population data for `user_list[x]._id` data rather than placing it with the `_id` property itself?

```
/// model

'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema,
  deepPopulate = require('mongoose-deep-populate')(mongoose);


var user_list_schema = new Schema({
   _id:{
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  soft_delete:{
    type:Boolean
  }

 });

var BusinessSchema = new Schema({

  title: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    trim: true,
    required: 'Title cannot be blank'
  },

  user_list:[user_list_schema],
  user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }
});

mongoose.model('Business', BusinessSchema);

///controller

Business.findById(id).populate('user', 'displayName').populate('user_list._id').exec(function (err, business) {
if (err) {
  return next(err);
} else if (!business) {
  return res.status(404).send({
    message: 'No business with that identifier has been found'
  });
}
req.business = business;
next();
});
```

Comment: Justin,

It's confusing what you are asking. You currently have a `user` model, a `user_list` model, and a `Business` model right? If so can you show the code for your different models?

Comment: @inspired Yeah sorry I'm kinda confused by the terminology I guess.  I've updated my model above.

Comment: ok great. Can you show what fields you want for your user?

Comment: @inspired ideally displayName, username & email address to be available. If you can just show me how to set things up with 1 field that would be a huge help and I could do the rest.